# chartjs not drawing with formated time for x-axis

Tags: javascript, jquery, chart.js, linechart, typeerror

I am trying to draw a line chart with time x-axis. But chart is giving me this error. I want to print the time in a certain format 'hh:mm:ss' but looks like this format is causing some issue. When i send hardcoded labels the chart is drawn correctly.

Chart.min.js:14 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined

This is my call stack
[image]

This is my code

```
    var timeFormat = 'h:mm:ss a';
function newDate(days) {
    //return moment().add(days, 'd').toDate();
    return moment().add(days, 'm').format(timeFormat);
}

function DrawTrendTempChart() {

    var temp_data_trend = {
        labels: [newDate(0), newDate(10), newDate(20), newDate(30), newDate(40), newDate(50), newDate(60)], // Date Objects,
        datasets: [{
            lineTension: 0,
            label: 'Trend',
            data: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
            pointRadius: 2,
            backgroundColor: ['transparent'],
            borderColor: [OrangeRGB],
            borderWidth: liveDataLineWidth,
            //fill: false,
            //borderDash: [5, 5],
        }]
    }

    var temp_options_trend = {
        scales: {
            xAxes: [{
                type: "time",
                time: {
                    format: timeFormat,
                    tooltipFormat: timeFormat,
                    unit: 'minute',
                    unitStepSize: 20,
                },
                scaleLabel: {
                    display: true,
                    labelString: 'Date'
                }
            }, ],
            yAxes: [{
                scaleLabel: {
                    display: true,
                    labelString: 'value'
                },
                ticks: {
                    autoSkip: false
                }
            }]
        },
        legend: { display: true },
        tooltips: { enabled: true },
        showTooltips: true,
        responsive: true,
        title: {
            display: true,
            text: "Trend Chart"
        }
    }

    var ctx = document.getElementById("sensorDataTrend").getContext("2d");
    myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'line',
        data: temp_data_trend,
        options: temp_options_trend
    });
}
```

Comment: I couldn't reproduce the error with your code. [See here](https://jsfiddle.net/d5a0pj31/)

Comment: which version of chartjs you have used?

Comment: Chart.js [v2.2.1](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.2.1/Chart.min.js)